# async/await deadlock caused by Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a couple of classes that look like this:

**Class REST**

```
public class REST
{   
    ...
    public async Task<Status> GetStatus()
    {
        var message =  new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost...");
        message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization",
            $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin:admin"))}");

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Logger**

```
public class Logger
{   
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim writeLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public async Task Log(int number, LogMessage message)
    {
        var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("O");
        var fileName = "C:/temp/random.log";
        writeLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                if (new FileInfo(fileName).Length >= 10000000)
                {
                    await WaitForRestCall(fileName);
                    File.Move(fileName, $"C:/temp/random_{Current}.log");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Logging message {number}, timestamp = {message.TimeStamp}");
                    using (var sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
                    {
                        var log = $"{number}\t{time}\t{message.Message}";
                        sw.WriteLine(log);
                    }

                    Current++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Logging message {number}, timestamp = {message.TimeStamp}");
                    using (var sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
                    {
                        var log = $"{number}\t{time}\t{message.Message}";
                        sw.WriteLine(log);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Logging message {number}, timestamp = {message.TimeStamp}");
                using (var sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
                {
                    var log = $"{number}\t{time}\t{message.Message}";
                    sw.WriteLine(log);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            writeLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    private async Task WaitForRestCall(string fileName)
    {
        var finishedReading = false;
        do
        {
            var check = await REST.Instance().GetStatus();
            if (!check.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for task to finish.");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                finishedReading = true
            }
        } while (!finishedReading);
    }
}
```

(Both are singleton classes, that's why the `Instance()` method is called there)

I'm testing this interaction between the classes with this Console app:

**Console**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static Task Log()
    {
        string oneKBMessage = "<1KB string here>"

        var logger = Logger.Instance();

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(i => Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await logger.Log(i, new LogMessage() { Message = oneKBMessage, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
        }));

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Now, I followed Stephen Cleary's advice to make everything async all the way up, but when the application has to check with the REST API if it doesn't return "Done" and goes to sleep, the next cycle of that `do/while` when the REST class calls the API it freezes everything there. I assume there's a deadlock, but I can't see why it's happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why not replace the Thread.Sleep with an awaitable Task.Wait?

Comment: @PmanAce I think you mean `Task.Delay` which is the async alternative to `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Does your `REST.Instance().GetStatus()` method have any locks in it?

Comment: @GabrielLuci No. You can see the code of `GetStatus()` in the original post, under REST

Comment: Right! sorry :) my eyes skipped over that.

Comment: @juharr yes indeed, thanks for the correction, need more coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple red flags:

First, change `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to `await Task.Delay(1000)` so you're not blocking the thread. That may be part of your problem, although I don't see quite how at the moment.

Second, your `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

There are two issues:

1. `Log()` returns a `Task` that you are not observing to see when it has completed. You are probably getting a compiler warning about that.
2. Your `Main` method is `void`, which means it can't use `await`.

The reason these are a problem is that the `await` keyword will *return* when it acts on an incomplete `Task` (and the rest of the method is signed up as the "continuation" to happen when after the waiting is done). Usually it returns its own `Task` object, but if it can't because the method is `void`, it returns nothing. But it still returns.

Because you're not doing anything with the `Task` returned from `Log()`, your `Main` method continues and you never know if it completes.

I see you are using `Console.ReadKey()` to keep the program running, which is "ok". But you could just change your `Main` method to `async Task` and `await Log()`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Log();
}
```

That is assuming you are using C# 7.1+, since that's when you could start returning a `Task` from `Main()`.

Also, you are creating 100,000 threads but only allowing one to work at any one time. Why not just create a regular `for` or `foreach` loop and do them one at a time?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    await logger.Log(i, new LogMessage() { Message = oneKBMessage, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
}
```

Then you don't even need the locks - at least for this specific use case. If there are other cases where you will call it from different threads, then keep the locks.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue with the REST call. However, now when the thread that makes the REST API call finishes executing and hits `ExitWriteLock()` it hangs the program there.

Comment: I added an update at the end of my answer. Might have something to do with all the threads combined with the locks, as Arman  and Theodor pointed out.

Comment: It's a PoC: I'm testing how the Logger class behaves when it's being bombarded by requests from different sources. Making it synchronic would defeat its purpose.

Comment: Don't confuse synchronous with parallel. It's asynchronous already (it frees the thread while it waits for things). What I'm suggesting is to not call it in parallel (more than one thread at a time). If you want to test how it runs in parallel, maybe try less threads. It might be that it's just hitting the ThreadPool limit, and that's what is causing the problem. How does it behave when you run 1000 thread?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the call `writeLock.EnterWriteLock();` blocks too many threads. Your program creates 100,000 `Task.Run` tasks at the same time, and all of them request ownership of the same lock. So all available threads in the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) are immediately blocked, and there is no thread available to process the continuation of the single asynchronous workflow that has acquired the ownership of the lock, and thus is allowed to make progress. The `ThreadPool` is designed to respond to this starvation event by injecting one new thread every 500 msec. This rate is obviously too slow for serving all 100,000 tasks in a timely manner.

If this is indeed the source of the problem, then a possible solution is to use a lock that can be awaited asynchronously, like the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim).

---

**Update:** another option instead of the `SemaphoreSlim` is the [`AsyncReaderWriterLock`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncReaderWriterLock) class, from Stephen Cleary's [Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/) package.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem now: after the thread that makes the HTTP call is finished processing, when it hits `ExitWriteLock()` it hangs the execution.

Answer (score 4):

Everything that stated by **Gabriel Luci** are completely true, but I want talk about the scenario that causes your application not responding:

1. You simultaneously start 100,000 threads, so all threads in thread pool will be consumed!
2. All of them except one wait behind your lock
3. One thread can enter the lock and is waited by `Thread.Sleep`
4. After sleep elapsed want to resume but no thread remains to continue execution
5. Even without any Sleep, because default number of threads in thread pool is far less than 100,000 , any newly created thread (each takes 500ms!) will be consumed to start new task instead of continuation already awaited task!
6. **Starvation!**

Comment: Indeed, I'm experiencing this issue after taking Gabriel Luci's suggestions.

Comment: @Heathcliff I think that's because default number of threads in thread pool is far less than 100000 and all newly created threads in thread pool (each one takes 500ms) consumed for running new task, instead of continuing execution after releasing lock! try to reduce 100000 or increase default number of threads in thread pool and see the results

Comment: It is. You were right with this diagnosis. I'm trying another approach to avoid having all those threads lock and not exhaust the thread pool. Thank you